# Where to put GitInfo hooks on Mac

Tags: revision-control, git, gitinfo

Where and how does one put the `post-checkout` and `post-commit` hooks for using the `gitinfo` package with latex on a Mac?

Example working directory:`/Volumes/Boxcryptor Classic/Git/randomproject`

On Windows there is a hidden folder `.git` within the working directory. On my Mac I cannot find it, I already tried `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE ; killall Finder`.

Comment: There should be a `.git` directory in any directory under Git control.  If you use the terminal, `ls -a` should show it.

Comment: I fixed spaces in my folder names and got navigation via 'cd' to the folder working. Then I opened a finder via 'open .' and finally had access.